# I am unable to figure out the error in the following code. Can someone assist me in this case?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

We define super digit of an integer  using the following rules:

Given an integer, we need to find the super digit of the integer.

If x has only 1 digit, then its super digit is x .
Otherwise, the super digit of x is equal to the super digit of the sum of the digits of x.
For example, the super digit of 9875  will be calculated as:

```
super_digit(9875)       9+8+7+5 = 29 
super_digit(29)     2 + 9 = 11
super_digit(11)     1 + 1 = 2
super_digit(2)      = 2
```

The number p is created by concatenating the string n, k times.

Here's the code which I have prepared:-

```
int superDigit(string n, int k) {
    
    static string m=n;
    for(int i=1;i<k;i++)
    {
       n=n+m;   
    }
    int num2=stoi(n);
    if(num2%10==num2)
    {
        return num2;
    }
    else
    {
            int digit{};
            int sum{};
            while (num2!=0)
            {
                digit=num2%10;
                sum+=digit;
                num2/=10;
            } 
            string sum1=to_string(sum);
            superDigit(sum1,0); 
     }    


}
```

It is showing the `error= "control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]"`

Comment: Your method does not return in the else block. This is also exactly what the error message is telling you: The control (of the function) reaches (an) end (in the else block) with no return of an int (you have non-void (int) function

Comment: Looks like the `superDigit(sum1,0);` statement in the `else` block should be `return superDigit(sum1,0);`.

Comment: not the issue, but getting single digits from a `std::string` is simpler than first converting to `int` and then iterate to get digits

Comment: compiler warnings are your friends https://godbolt.org/z/boPcxnzsn don't ignore them

Comment: Short version: `int super_digit(int n) {
int d = n % 9;
return n ? d ? d : 9 : 0;
}`

Comment: @Matt Very nice insight.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a while ago and i figured out that the compiler assumes what if the if statement didin't execute, so in this case the program will continue at the else block and when it reaches the end of it it needs to return an int but u got no return at the end of the else. so just add one that returns something